# Ruby array of hashes find values by key

Tags: ruby

I have an array like below

> [{500=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"Hock Tong Bee Pte Ltd/ Corner stone wines",
>   "created_at"=>Thu, 19 Jan 2017 18:10:35 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Thu,
>   19 Jan 2017 18:10:35 UTC +00:00, "website"=>nil, "status"=>nil,
>   "industry_type_id"=>1, "major_category_id"=>1,
>   "minor_category_id"=>75, "save_as_draft"=>false, "company_id"=>1}},
>   {600=>{"id"=>2, "name"=>"Continental Wines", "created_at"=>Thu, 19 Jan
>   2017 18:10:35 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Thu, 19 Jan 2017 18:10:35 UTC
>   +00:00, "website"=>nil, "status"=>nil, "industry_type_id"=>1, "major_category_id"=>1, "minor_category_id"=>75,
>   "save_as_draft"=>false, "company_id"=>2}}]

I have key's like 500/600 from this array i want tot get that object.
I need to write one method, I will pass key only that should return appropriate object. Example if I send key is 500 result should be

> {"id"=>1, "name"=>"Hock Tong Bee Pte Ltd/ Corner stone wines",
>   "created_at"=>Thu, 19 Jan 2017 18:10:35 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Thu,
>   19 Jan 2017 18:10:35 UTC +00:00, "website"=>nil, "status"=>nil,
>   "industry_type_id"=>1, "major_category_id"=>1,
>   "minor_category_id"=>75, "save_as_draft"=>false, "company_id"=>1}

Anyone have idea on how to achieve this in Ruby?

Comment: sounds like you want to use a Hash as the root data structure instead of an Array.

Comment: `array.find { |hash| hash.keys.include?(500) }.values.first`

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We'd like to see what your attempt to solve the question was. Without that it looks very much like you want us to solve it for you. Also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 will help explain.

Comment: "key's like 500/600"? You have a key that is a string containing two actual keys? Or does that mean you have keys like 500 or 600? Detail and accuracy is important when you ask for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe simple reduce method should work:

```
hash = [{500=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"Hock Tong Bee Pte Ltd/ Corner stone wines", "created_at"=>"Thu, 19 Jan 2017 18:10:35 UTC +00:00", "updated_at"=>"Thu, 19 Jan 2017 18:10:35 UTC +00:00", "website"=>nil, "status"=>nil, "industry_type_id"=>1, "major_category_id"=>1, "minor_category_id"=>75, "save_as_draft"=>false, "company_id"=>1}}, {600=>{"id"=>2, "name"=>"Continental Wines", "created_at"=>"Thu, 19 Jan 2017 18:10:35 UTC +00:00", "updated_at"=>"Thu, 19 Jan 2017 18:10:35 UTC +00:00", "website"=>nil, "status"=>nil, "industry_type_id"=>1, "major_category_id"=>1, "minor_category_id"=>75, "save_as_draft"=>false, "company_id"=>2}}]
your_value = hash.reduce({}) { |h, v| h.merge v }[500]
```

Comment: Hi @oMiKey thanks for your input. I have another question regarding this. Can I ask?

Comment: I have this array [{103=>{"id"=>107, "country"=>"USA"}}, {103=>{"id"=>108, "country"=>"UK"}, {104=>{"id"=>109, "country"=>"USA"}}, {104=>{"id"=>110, "country"=>"USA"}}, {104=>{"id"=>111, "country"=>"AUS"}}] 

I have 104, USA to 
In the view I want to show
1) count as 2 (how many matches)
2) any one if the object {104=>{"id"=>109, "country"=>"USA"}

Do you have any idea about this? @oMikey

Comment: Thanks a lot @oMikeY. You did this in few min. I struggleing on hours :( May I know your twitter account

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134027/discussion-between-vinothini-and-omikey).

Comment: Rather than creating one large hash, wouldn't it be more efficient to check each hash in turn, looking for the desired key? That way, the search terminates as soon as the target key is found (if it is found): `h = hash.find { |h| h.keys.include?(500) }; h.nil? nil : h[500]`. btw, `hash` is an unusual name for an array. :-)